# Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0,

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nuget

I am working with EF .
I am trying to execute this line

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{           
     return View(obj.FindSemesterById(id));
}
```

I installed EF Version 5 on my project.

But i get this error :

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, 
>       PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's 
>        manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 
>        0x80131040)

My web.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EducationDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EducationModel.csdl|res://*/EducationModel.ssdl|res://*/EducationModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=EducationDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

    </assemblyBinding>

  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: why not install EF version 6, as it's clearly looking for that?

Comment: The available version that i can find in nuget package is version 5.

Comment: http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/ <-- are you following these instructions?

Comment: I have 4 projects in my solution .all of my projects have a same version of EF

Comment: @Michael Edenfield:i just search in nuget package and installed that

Comment: How should i write this command?

Comment: Why did you install EF5 when clearly some your projects require EF6?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov because the available EF for in nuget just is version 5

Comment: @user3446201, hmmm, weird, am I misreading the 6.1.0 here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/ Doesn't quite look like 5.0.

Comment: when i try to install that using your command i got this error :Install-Package : The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.nuget.org'
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  EntityFramework 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: @user3446201, then you should have mentioned that in your question. That's an entirely different problem. You actually couldn't install EF6. Judging from the error message (`The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.nuget.org'`) it appears that your DNS server is not working properly or maybe you do not have access to the internet from the computer you tried to install the NuGet from. Maybe it was behind a corporate firewall or something.

Comment: So i just try to use a proxy

Comment: I install a EF version 6 .but the error is changed to this:
Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: @user3446201 I have edited my answer,that is because in your web.config file its referencing EF version 5.0.0.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the comments section it appears that you weren't able to install the latest version of EF from the public NuGet source because your computer didn't have direct access to the internet and was unable to resolve the `www.nuget.org` domain. Normally if you configure a proxy in your internet settings, Visual Studio will use this proxy when installing a NuGet from the public repository.

So once you have installed the latest [`EF 6.1.0`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/) package in your project, the error will go away. Currently you seem to be using some older version of the package and you have projects in your solution that require v6.

Comment: So i changed it to EF6 .but another error comes out :
Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: It appears that you have referenced some project in your solution that explicitly requires EF 5. This could happen if you are using some third party libraries. Start by analyzing what packages you are using and look for a version of them compiled and compatible with EF6. You should install consistent versions. Yo ucan't just throw some arbitrary NuGets in your solution and expect that it will work. You should also realize what those NuGets are doing, what and what dependencies they have to avoid those kind of conflicts.

Answer (score 9):

First, check which version of EF you using. You can update the EF version from NuGet Packet Manager.

Go to your Project solution - > 'Manage NuGet packet for Solution', click 'Manage' on 'Entity Framework'.

and also Check your `app.config` . Maybe the wrong version number is being referenced here.

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

It's referencing EF Version 5.0.0.0

Comment: No as Darin Dimitrov said,first you try to manage the Nuget Package.Then your problem will get resolve.

Answer (score 6):

**Open** Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console

**then run**

```
PM> install-package entityframework -version 6.0.0.0
```

**Or You can update it to latest version using below command**

```
PM> Update-Package entityframework
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Nuget to uninstall EF then add it again, Clean and rebuild your project, that worked like a charm. The "uninstall" part in my case was critical, I did a lot of reinstallations and updates and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar problem and same error as you mentioned.

I solved it differently. I noticed that EntityFramework.dll was added to packages folder under Solution Explorer.
So I copied EntityFramework.dll from that folder to the bin folder under Solution Explorer and it worked.
I know this is not your answer, it may be helpful to other so I just added it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today. I had 3 projects in a solution two of which had EF 6.0.0.0 and one of them had 5.0.0.0` I upgraded the version of that one project when I found this issue. The error went away.

**Note:** I simply went to the References folder of each project and saw the properties of EntityFramework to find out the version of Entity.

Comment: This just repeats the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

My solution has four projects in it. This is a different computer than the one I first created by solution on, so I opened Tools, then NuGet package manager, clicked "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution, found Entity Framework and clicked it once.  Then clicked on the Manage button that appeared.

NuGet offered to install EF to one of my projects in the Solution, so I did that. That's when I started getting this error.

Going back to NuGet and checking the boxes to install EF into All of the four projects in the Solution fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your project name conflicts with a nuget package you referenced.