# Windows Service throwing a FileLoadException

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, windows-services

I am developing a windows service, but every time I start it, it shows an exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579545/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-entityframework-version-6-0-0-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue figured it out. I was how created the project. I had a project named EntityFramework and that project had the .net entity framework ddl as a reference. When I build the solution it was conflicting with the project ddl and the actual .net entity framework ddl. The solution therefore was to rename the project to something else. :)